# Is there a way to figure out if a touchpad is broken, even if it's unsupported by Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, debugging, touchpad, hardware-compatibility

(I asked another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551234/how-do-i-go-about-writing-a-driver-for-an-unsupported-touch-pad-in-a-laptop) that led to this question. I'm going to repost some of the command line output that I think is relevant.)

I found an old laptop in my garage (Lenovo IdeaPad U260) and after replacing the motherboard and CPU and installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, it works almost as good as new. The only problem is that the touchpad doesn't work, and from my understanding, it isn't recognized.

Here's output from `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0f/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0f/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0f/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=5986 Product=0195 Version=1423
N: Name="Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c52f Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech USB Receiver"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.000D/input/input38
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c52f Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.000E/input/input39
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=300ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1 130ff38b17c000 677bfad9415fed 9ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10
```

As well as from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0195 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e00d Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1 Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As far as I understand, it looks like this touch pad isn't supported by the kernel, and I have the most up to date stable version.

If it's not recognized, are there other commands I could run to investigate more? And if not, or after checking out additional outputs without success, then is there a way for me to figure out if the touchpad is functional and not just broken? I wouldn't mind debugging through Linux or with more physical means with the actual hardware. (My hope is to do it through Linux, so that's why I posted this question on this site - I apologize if this isn't the best place for it, I'd be happy to ask elsewhere with a pointer to the more preferred site.)

I don't have Windows to boot into, I'd like to not buy another Windows 7 key (and the product key I have for the laptop can't get me another ISO from Microsoft, I'd have to go to Lenovo for repair tools), and I don't even wanna think about installing Windows 10 onto this old thing (I love this laptop and don't want to make it suffer).

Comment: This is not the politically correct thing to say, but I would start with Windows. I think that you can still download the windows 2008 server iso for free, which should be compatible  with windows 7 drivers, and will work competely legit for 6 months or so. Once you have the vendor's drivers working, you have a lead from which to start searching for specs and docs. Poking in the dark and doing guesswork is only a waste of time. FWIW, on my cheap ideapad I had some 8 years ago or so (I forgot the model), both the webcam and the touchscreen were on the USB bus, connected to an internal hub.

Comment: That's what I was afraid would be the best way to start @mosvy , but I wasn't aware there was an older ISO available for free download, so that's not terrible at least. Thanks for the help, and thanks for the USB lead too!

Comment: you could also try a live cd distro, like knoppix .... i have used knoppix in the past and it seemed to have drivers to run almost anything

Comment: And if it's working with Windows, you can use the system hardware information UI etc. to find out the most important part: How the touchpad hardware connects to the rest of the system. Knoppix probably won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @mosvy 's suggestion, I flashed a windows 2008 server ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5023) using rufus (this is the first time I flashed a non-Linux based OS with it and it worked just as well). In the live USB portion of it, before installing the OS, I could move the cursor and click with my USB mouse, but moving the cursor nor clicking with either button worked for the touchpad. So, I've come to the conclusion that the touch pad is likely broken.